# How do you convert a stored procedure using dynamic SQL into a non-dynamic SQL one(SSRS)?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I've been working on SSRS reports, and for one of my stored procedures , it uses dynamic SQL suchthat i'm getting this error:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

So I've googled that error a bit, but it's still hazy to me..

My stored-procedure takes in a few parameters that  are toggle-type, like the followin:

```
@CompleteType INT = NULL,
/*
 * 0 - Routed
 * 1 - Targeted
 * 2 - Offerwall
 */

@SourceType BIT = NULL,
/*
 * Works if @AccountID is not null
 * (should only be used if @AccountID has a single value)
 *
 * 0 - Owned by @AccountID
 * 1 - External (not owned by @AccountID)
 */

@SurveyStatus INT = NULL,
/*
 * NULL - All Surveys
 * 0 - Completes Approved Surveys
 * 1 - Invoiced Surveys
 */

@IsSupplierUser BIT = 0
/*
 * used to decide whether to display FEDSurveyName or SupplierSurveyName
```

The problem occurs in these two  code  blocks here(they're not contiguous):

```
-- Initial Survey Name
    IF @IsSupplierUser = 0
        SET @SQL += CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,ts.FEDSurveyName as ''Initial Survey Name'''

    ELSE
        SET @SQL += CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,ts.SupplierSurveyName as ''Initial Survey Name'''
```

then this one:

```
-- Complete Survey Name
IF @IsSupplierUser = 0
    SET @SQL += CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,cs.FEDSurveyName as ''Complete Survey Name'''
ELSE
    SET @SQL += CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,cs.SupplierSurveyName as ''Complete Survey Name'''
```

We have both a  `ts.FEDSurveyName` and a `cs.FEDSurveyName` , and the same for `SupplierSurveyName`  respectively.   I appreciate any tips! thanks

Comment: As someone who downvotes at the drop of a hat, I don't understand why this question is being downvoted.

Comment: There's nothing in what you've showed us so far that should result in that error.  Print out your `@SQL` variables before you execute them, and then post the failing one(s) here.

Comment: This is because of naming output same way twice in code even in different branches. See the answer, should work when you set field name only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE
@IsSupplierUser BIT = 0,
@SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) ='init'
-- Initial Survey Name
SELECT @SQL += CASE @IsSupplierUser
    WHEN 0 THEN CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,ts.FEDSurveyName'
    ELSE CHAR(13) + CHAR(9) + N' ,ts.SupplierSurveyName'
END + N' as ''Initial Survey Name'''
SELECT @SQL
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10397

Answer (score 1):

I assume these snippets are for generating your select list.  To convert this to non-dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    When @IsSupplierUser = 0 Then ts.FEDSurveyName 
    Else ts.SupplierSurveyName 
  END as 'Initial Survey Name',
  ts.SomeOtherColumn,
  etc.
  ...
FROM ...
```

Of course "etc." just indicates you continuing with other columns, you can have another case statement for the other conditional column you showed.